# std::string and placement new

Tags: c++, string, placement-new

I found this example of using placement new in C++, and it doesn't make sense to me. 
It is my view that this code is exception-prone, since more memory than what was allocated may be used.

```
char *buf  = new char[sizeof(string)];
string *p = new (buf) string("hi");
```

If "string" is the C++ STD::string class,then buf will get an allocation
the size of an empty string object (which with my compiler gives 28 bytes),
and then the way I see it if you initialize your string with more chars you might
exceed the memory allocated. For example:

```
string *p = new (buf) string("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
```

On my VS this seems to be working nevertheless, and I'm not sure if this is because
the exception is somehow waived or I simply don't understand how string works.

Can someone help clarify?

Comment: When `string("hiiii...")` runs it may do a `new char[]` to get additional memory to store the text, and if that throws then it's important that `p` is not `delete`d (that would be Undefined Behaviour) but `buf` is `delete[]`ed (otherwise there'd be a memory leak).  So all up - error-prone for exceptions, even if not "exception-prone".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size returned by `sizeof` is the number of bytes required to store the members of the class, with some implementation-defined padding. That memory must be allocated before the constructor of `std::string` can be called.

However, when the constructor runs, it may allocate a larger amount of memory, which indeed it must in order to store large strings. That amount of memory is not part of the `sizeof` size, and you don't need to allocate it yourself.

Comment: That's what I was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

You're misunderstanding the (typical) internal implementation of std::string.  Usually it's implemented something like this:

```
class string {
protected:
    char *buffer;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t length;

public:
    // normal interface methods
};
```

The key point is that there are *two* distinct blocks of memory:  one for the `string` object itself, containing the members shown above, and one for the content of the string.  When you do your placement `new`, it's only the string object that is placed into the provided memory, *not* the memory for `buffer`, where the content of the string is stored.  That is allocated separately, automatically, by the `string` class as needed.

Comment: Nit-pick: I've looked at a few Standard Library implementations and they're all implemented with a `char* end_;` rather than `length()`, meaning typical iteration ala `for (i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)` will have a trivially cheap `end()`, but `size()` will require a pointer subtraction.  No biggy and not particularly relevant here, but IMHO worth keeping in the back of your mind....

Comment: @TonyD VS8 and G++ 4.3.4 use capacity and length fields, not an `end` field. In any case, this answer is not intended to be a tutorial or debate on how to efficiently implement `std::string`, but a pedagogical example to facilitate understanding.